# Removing Spaces Between Documents

Tags: formatting, include, layout, vertical-spacing

How can I remove spaces inserted between different documents.

```
\include{project/Chapters/doc1}
\include{project/Chapters/doc2}
```

I want these two documents glued together with no spaces.
Thank you!

Comment: `\include` will always start a new page by design. Try `\input` instead.

Comment: Use `\input` rather than `\include` to avoid spaces being inserted between the two sets of content: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250/21344 (this has some other side effects too, check the link for details)

Comment: You have not provided an example so we have to guess... `\include` forces a page break  so you can use `\input` instead but if your files start with a heading such as `\chapter{...}` then in most classes `\chapter` also forces a new page. But you do not say what document class you are using, or if your files start  with a chapter heading.